# How to automatically run a Python script in the cloud on scheduled days

Tags: python, cloud

I have a Google Colab notebook. This notebook has to be ran every few days. Is there a way in which I can run a python script in the cloud on scheduled days?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a server or cloud platform to host your code and schedule it to run in that environment. I don't think it's possible in Colab.

Have a look at Heroku Scheduler (a free option): https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/clock-processes-python

Other options might be AWS, Google, or Python Anywhere, as mentioned in [this article](https://blog.finxter.com/how-to-schedule-your-python-script-for-free-on-heroku/)